# Invoke ColdFusion method with on click in JQuery

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

I have a page which displays a list of files that a user has uploaded. Its like this:

```
<ul id="FileUploader">
<li>
<a href="directory/filename1.pdf">Filename1</a> 
<a href="#" class="DeleteFileUpload">Delete</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="directory/filename2.pdf">Filename2</a> 
<a href="#" class="DeleteFileUpload">Delete</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

I have a CFC with a method which needs to know which file to delete. Because this is not Form, I'm not sure how to pass the data to the CFC to get it to delete the file.

CFC example:

```
<cffunction name="DeleteUpload" access="remote" returnformat="JSON">

<cfargument name="Filename" required="true"> //which filename to delete
<cffile action = "delete" file = "c:\files\upload\#Arguments.Filename#"> //delete the file

   <cfquery> // Update SQL table to remove filename reference
       DELETE FROM UploadsTable
       WHERE Filename = '#Arguments.Filename#'
    </cfquery>
<cfset success = true> // all done so set variable to true
<cfreturn success> // returns success as JSON to notify Jquery of deletion
</cffunction>
```

How can I use JQuery Ajax to pass the value of the Filename to the CFC so that it knows which one to delete and then after receiving the successful result inform the user with an alert?

I know how to do the above with a FORM, but because this is not a form I'm a bit confused. This is as far as my JQuery has come:

```
$("#FileUploader").on('click', '.DeleteFileUpload', function () {
    $(this).parent('li').remove();
});
```

This only removes the `<li>` from the DOM. I also need to get the Filename and pass it to the CFC somehow.

Comment: Remember that Coldfusion is executed on the server and JS is executed in the browser (at least in this case it is.) So, you should create a ColdFusion method that you can POST or GET information to. Then you should be able to call that in JavaScript using Ajax.

Comment: Yep I understand that. I just want to pass the value of the Filename to a CFC. I think I need to use $.ajax "Get" but not sure.

Comment: If you're submitting data to be processed, then you should probably use $.post - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: Even though there is no form on the page? is that ok?

Comment: Yes... essentially you would be submitting form values with JS and your Coldfusion method would process the submitted form. Though, the solution given by @Jelle Kralt looks like it will also do the trick. Just be aware that technically, POST should be usied when submitting data (like the filename in your case) that modifies something in the server. It stays RESTful if POST is used for changes and GET is just used for retrieving info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to add an ajax call to the CFC:

```
$("#FileUploader").on('click', '.DeleteFileUpload', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('li').remove();
    $.ajax('/path/to/your.cfc?method=DeleteUpload&Filename=' + $(this).attr('href'));
});
```

You'd need to change the href of the delete link to the file path (as a reference) and disable the click by using preventDefault()

```
<a href="directory/filename2.pdf" class="DeleteFileUpload">Delete</a>
```

If you don't like to put the file path in the href you could always put it in a data attribute or get the href from the sibling link.

Comment: I would suggest that the `li` not be removed until you have successfully returned a message from the server - You can do this by adding callbacks to the `$.ajax()` call. If you remove the `li` from the page first, if there is an issue on the server, the UI will not properly reflect the current state of the data.

Comment: @ScottStroz I understand what you mean but I do not fully agree with you. I tend to perform the removal while the ajax is still running. It's all about the illusion of speed, the user gets instant feedback from the webpage when actually the call might still be running. If you r ColdFusion code and server performs like it should, you shouldn't worry too much about the call not running correctly. If there is a problem on the server, you'd have to communicate that to the user, most users won't understand this anyway. If your server is working correct the percentage of errors should be minimal.

Comment: I am not one to play the percentages when it comes to code. The problem need not be a CF related issue. Could be a connectivity issue. Either way, if you remove the element from the UI before it has actually been removed, you run the risk of increased user confusion. And, you should ALWAYS worry about your HTTP requests running correctly. Always.

Comment: Also..I prefer the reality of correctness over the illusion of speed.

Comment: As Scott stated.. only remove the li once the delete actually happens.  Also, you need some serious security around your ajax call and cfc. It would be fairly trivial to write something that could find and delete all the files and data.

Comment: Thinking about this more, I think there is a better way, that combines your lust for the 'illusion of speed' and my desire for the 'reality of correctness'. Instead of removing the element form the DOM when the button is clicked, simply hide it. When server response comes back with 'success', then remove it. If server response comes back with anything other than 'success', show it again, along with a nice message explaining what happened.

Comment: @ScottStroz That is indeed a very nice solution :)

Comment: Can comment now....and just wanted to weigh in that Scott Stroz and Dave Ferguson both have the right idea. Don't 'just hope', and always handle failures. Silent failures are a nightmare to debug and fix.

Comment: Thank you for the comments and suggestion. I'll look at the security aspect Dave... but currently not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

(New to participating stackoverflow, can't comment yet.)

Don't just remove the element and pray. Removing it immediately, having it fail, and then showing a "Hey, whoopsie!" message is embarrassing and confusing.

Instead, satisfy the immediate feedback goal by showing the item is on its way to the wastebin, and then kill it when it's gone:

```
$("#FileUploader").on('click', '.DeleteFileUpload', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  // Do something showing that we're trying a delete...
  $(this).text('Deleting...')  

  var uri = '/path/to/your.cfc?method=DeleteUpload&Filename=' + encodeURI(     $(this).attr('href')) )

  $.ajax(uri)
    .done( function() {
      $(this).parent('li').remove();
    })
    .fail( function() {
      // Let them know we have a goof and let them try again
      alert('Whoa! That couldn't be deleted!')
      $(this).text('Deleted...')  
    })    
});
```

You'd then want to consider preventing the user from clicking twice by un/re-binding the handler.