# Can't remove parent <li> on success or complete but can before

Tags: jquery

Here is my JQuery (from my previous question here [Invoke ColdFusion method with on click in JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20960527/invoke-coldfusion-method-with-on-click-in-jquery))

```
$("#FileUploader").on('click', '.DeleteFileUpload', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).text('Deleting...'); // changes link text to say its deleting
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'mycfc.cfc?method=deletefile',
            data: {
                Filename: $(this).attr('href') // name of file to delete is in the href 
            },
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function () {
                $('#loader').show(); // show a loading spinner
            },
            success: function () {
            $('#loader').hide(); // on succcess hide the spinner
        $(this).closest('li').remove(); // should remove the closest li which displays the file name but this does not work
            },
            complete: function () {
        $(this).parent('li').remove(); // should remove the parent li which displays the file name but this does not work
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("An error has occured.");
            }

        });
    });
```

So I have tried to remove the closest `li` and the parent `li` (both should do the same thing) and neither work. But if I put the line of code before the Ajax() function then it works like this:

```
$("#FileUploader").on('click', '.DeleteFileUpload', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).parent('li').remove(); // this works and the li is removed!
       .........
```

Can anyone please help me work out why I can't remove the `li` in the success/complete area?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `this` inside the ajax is not in the context you think.

Try this:

```
$("#FileUploader").on('click', '.DeleteFileUpload', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var self = $(this);

    //......... later on inside the ajax call

    success: function () {
        $('#loader').hide();
        self.closest('li').remove();
    },
    complete: function () {
        self.parent('li').remove(); 
    },
```

You can also use the [**context**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) option of ajax.

```
$.ajax({
    //...
    context: this,
    success: function () {
            $('#loader').hide();
            $(this).closest('li').remove();
        },
        complete: function () {
            $(this).parent('li').remove(); 
        },
```

Comment: Do I still use `self` when I have `context:this` or can I just use `this` word instead?

Comment: @volumeone, then you can use your code as you had, I will correct. Thanks

Comment: Brilliant I realised it was just a typo but thought I'd double check. Voted as answer thank you friend.